# how to find second maximum repetitive string

Tags: javascript

am able to find 1st maximum of repetitive strings in an array, could not able to find second maximum repetitive string
expected output is bbb

```js
function duplicateCount(arr) {
  let counts = {};
  arr.forEach((_each) => {
    counts[_each] = (counts[_each] || 0) + 1;
  })
  let max = 0;
  let maxStr = '';
  Object.keys(counts).forEach((key, index) => {
    if (counts[key] > max) {
      max = counts[key]
      maxStr = key;
    }

  })
  return maxStr;
}

console.log(duplicateCount(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"]))
```

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find the `count` then `sort` and get the `second` element. Easy...

using [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
function duplicateCount(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return "Empty array";

  const count = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (!acc[curr]) acc[curr] = 1;
    else ++acc[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});

  const keysSorted = Object.keys(count).sort((a, b) => count[b] - count[a]);

  // If there is single element in sorted array then return the element at 0 index else element at 1 index. You can also use if-else, but that's just old school method
  return keysSorted?.[1]?? keysSorted[0];
}

console.log(duplicateCount(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"]));
```

Comment: Oh man I really like that `count[b] - count[a]`. You should drop the "Easy..." though...

Comment: The best thing is using `return keysSorted?.[1]?? keysSorted[0];`

Comment: '??' what it is called

Comment: Nullish coalescing operator (??). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. Just an observation - `keysSorted` function can simply be `const keysSorted = Object.keys(count).sort((a, b) => count[b] - count[a]);`

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Yeah its just personal preference. BTW updated code thanks 

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the keys and get the first one with the second high value.

```js
function duplicateCount(array) {
  const counts = {};
  array.forEach(value => counts[value] = (counts[value] || 0) + 1);
  
  return Object
      .keys(counts)
      .sort((a, b) => counts[b] - counts[a])
      .find((k, i, a) => counts[k] !== counts[a[0]]);  
}

console.log(duplicateCount(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"]))
```

Comment: .find((k, i, a) => counts[k] !== counts[a[0]]);could u explain a bit

Comment: if you have a count of thee for two items, you get the one with a count of less than three.

Comment: What happens when there is only one element in an array `console.log(duplicateCount(["aaa"]));` then it will return undefined.

Comment: I mean that corner case should be covered also...Just for curiosity

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```js
var arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"];

var map = arr.reduce(function(p, c) {
  p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});

var sorted = Object.keys(map).sort(function(a, b) {
  return map[b] - map[a];
});

console.log(sorted[1]);
```

If you prefer *arrow functions* (ES6):

```js
var arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "bbb", "aaa", "aaa"];

var map = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
  return p;
}, {});

var sorted = Object.keys(map).sort((a, b) => map[b] - map[a]);

console.log(sorted[1]);
```

Comment: What happen when there is only one element in an array `console.log(duplicateCount(["aaa"]));`

Comment: @decpk In that case, `sorted` will be `undefined`. But that's not the OP's scenario.